# onhashchange event casuing invalid markup validation

Tags: javascript, html

hope I don't sound like an idiot posting this but using:

```
<body onhashchange="HashChangeHandler();">
```

Is causing an invalid markup validation.

Is there somewhere else I can put it other than the body tag?

I know there's `window.onhashchange = funcRef;` or `window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);` but I have no idea where to put it, if that makes sense.

The site still works perfectly but the invalid markup flag is bugging me!

Comment: When do u need to call the HashChangeHandler method ? after loading the page or before loading the page or does it not matter when u call it ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight — Presumably it needs to be called when the fragment identifier changes. Hence it's use in an event handler.

Comment: You can try to add it as window.onload = HashChangeHandler; inside the script tags(<script type="text/javascript"></script>) of the head tag. That's gotta solve u r problem .

Comment: I'm dynamically loading content to a div using AJAX and my anchors use hashtags so that I can preserve a history without using pushstate, hence the onhashchange to listen for it.

Comment: "preserve a history without using pushstate" — Use pushstate, pushstate is great, [depending on the fragment id to load external content is horrible](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs). (and a hashtag is a `#` character followed by a *search phrase* for automatic linking on UGC, not something you put at the end of a URI).

Comment: Sorry about that. Blame twitter culture for the hashtag reference :-) and thanks for the help. Same to anyone else who has commented, it is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there's … but I have no idea where to put it, if that makes sense.

In a `<script>` element. That's all.

```
<script>
function thingy(e) {
    alert('changed');
}
window.addEventListener("hashchange", thingy, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it was as simple as that :-) I just wasn't sure if I could sit it inside a script element at the top of the page. Not thinking straight this morning. Exactly why I was worried of sounding like a fool for something so simple. Thanks.